# How to use WMI queries to see if a file is dropped in a folder

Tags: ssis, wmi, wmi-query

I'm using a wmi query inside a ssis wmi event task to determine if a file is dropped in a folder.  Below is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10
WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DirectoryContainsFile"
AND TargetInstance.GroupComponent = "Win32_Directory.Name=\"f:\\\\append\input\""
```

I don't care about what the name of the file is, I just want to know if any files were dropped in there.

The wmi task says the query is invalid.  am I missing something?
of note, my OS is Winserver 2012 R2 standard.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5 
WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' 
    AND TargetInstance.Drive = 'F:' 
    AND TargetInstance.Path = '\\append\\input\\' 
    AND TargetInstance.Extension = 'csv'
```

This works like a beast.  Hope it helps for someone else.